# How to get form output value on same HTML form page?

Tags: php, html

I am looking to submit a HTML form file (home.html) with PHP action file (action.php) to display the output on same home.html file after processing through action.php.

I got many scripts solving this problem with .php file, Is it possible to do the same with HTML?

home.html

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
Enter Numeric Value: <input type="number" name="num">
<input type="Submit" value="Calculate">
</form>
```

action.php

```
<?php 
    $a=$_POST["num"];
    echo "Contact our sales person for higher volume of Emails";
?>
```

Comment: *"to display the output on same home.html file"* - You can't do that, unless you instruct Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP. Otherwise, you'd need to use an iframe, or rename your `.html` to `.php`

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `home` file into a PHP file and point the form action to it, then you can simply use the POST/GET data and display it on the page:

I have added the use of "[htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)" to more it a little more secure

home.php

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['num']))
    {
        echo htmlentities($_POST['num']);
    }

?>

<form action="home.php" method="post">
Enter Numeric Value: <input type="number" name="num">
<input type="Submit" value="Calculate">
</form>
```

Comment: @Fluffeh: I know the things you suggested, but i was curious to know, is it possible same thing we can do with HTML only. thanks for the answer

Comment: @user3665127 you can also use javascript and ajax to do this

Comment: @user3665127 In HTML, No. You can however embed JS/Ajax and do it if you *cannot* use PHP, but the PHP solution is the easiest by far.

Comment: @Fluffeh Unless you instruct Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP, as per my comment under OP's question.

Comment: @Catalin Deaconescu : I am looking for output on same HTML page only, please suggest me how JS and Ajax can help.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Not saying no, but if you do that, it is PHP with a HTML extension - which is PHP whatever dress you put on it :)

Comment: @Fluffeh Indeed it is the best solution. However OP's question specifically asks if it can be done using `.html` file extension.

Comment: Instead of sending the `post` from the form, you get the values from the form in JS, send the with Ajax to the php file, check it's result and then depending on the result show a message / change the page / whatever you need. You can take a look at some jquery examples using Ajax here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @Catalin Deaconescu: Hi i got it using simple Ajax and JS file. I just pass the php result to ajax file, that's included in html file. thanks for valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, first load the HTML file, then pull it into the PHP file:

home.html:

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
Enter Numeric Value: <input type="number" name="num" value="<?=$a?>">
<input type="Submit" value="Calculate">
</form>
```

Notice the "value" field and the php code inserted there.

action.php:

```
<?php
    $a=$_POST["num"];
    echo "Contact our sales person for higher volume of Emails";

    require 'home.html';
?>
```

Simply require'ing the home.html file.

First you load home.html in your browser, enter a number, submit the form to action.php. Then when action.php loads, it displays the appropriate message, pulls in the home.html page, and loads the variable $a into the form field. When loaded as a plain HTML file, the PHP code is ignored by the browser, but parsed when the action.php file require's the HTML file.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Do re-think this and read some of the comments under OP's question and the other answer.

Comment: That -1, it's mine. Re-read my comment above. Especially [`this comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808198/how-to-get-form-output-value-on-same-html-form-page#comment36623353_23808198)

Comment: @Fred -ii- Cool, comments reread. What particularly do you think is a problem with this option? I've used this technique now and then, and just tested it to be doubly sure. PHP requires HTML files just fine and even parses the php code.

Comment: You want the OP to use `value="<?=$a?>">` using `.html` as the extension? You say it worked for you... why? I know the why, I just want you to tell me.

Comment: Hi Fred. No sweat. The value="<?=$a?>" works because the action.php is require'ing it. In this case there's no need to tell apache to parse html files with the PHP processor.

Comment: Ah I see what you're doing. Ok I get it now. I've removed my -1 and replaced with a +1. Tricky (sneaky lol) but it works.

Comment: From the manual: "When a file is included, parsing drops out of PHP mode and into HTML mode at the beginning of the target file, and resumes again at the end. For this reason, any code inside the target file which should be executed as PHP code must be enclosed within valid PHP start and end tags." http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php